# Manage annotations and cards via Youtube data API v3.0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am wondering is there a way to manager annotations and cards via Youtube data API V3.0

Answer (score 5):

There is no official support for YouTube annotations. You can updates a [channel's metadata](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update).

To see how to update InVideo programming annotations, you can see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqtuSRe3QLo)