# How to add Youtube Video annotation using Youtube API V3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to add a Youtube video with annotation using Youtube api v3 in php.

I have been unable to find any information in the documentation as to how to create annotations though the API.

Does the Youtube API allow us to create annotation through API?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: i haven't found any API documentation on Annotation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31616552/2223410

Comment: OK I will give you that its hard to find info about this in the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota  found this to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqtuSRe3QLo

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo . i have already watched  this video. Youtube cannel api update only update channel branding and feature content.

Comment: then I strongly suspect that this is something that cant be done.